# Edittext focus when not value is not valid

Tags: android

I am trying to catch if the input valid is valid, when the value is invalid the focus should be set on that edittext.  Now, This one is partially working. The problem is when is go to another Edittext, the requestFocus seems to work but not exacly, The second edittext was the one was focused and when i type, the second edittext is the one that being editted

```
edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

        if (!hasFocus){

            if (isValid(edittext.getText().toString())) {

                edittext.requestFocus(); 
            }
        }
    }
});
```

this what happens on the ui.

[image]

I use ButterKnife to add views on onCreate

```
  @InjectView(R.id.password_edittext)
    EditText edittext;

    @InjectView(R.id.confirm_password_edittext)
    EditText edittext2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach the code.
What the names of the 2 textEdit var?
They may have the same name?
May not have connected between the variables and the XML code correctly?